# ¿Cómo permitir únicamente valores positivos en un <input>?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, entrada

Necesito comprobar el contenido de un `<input>` en el que sólo se pueden introducir números enteros mayores que 0 (del 1 a X). ¿Cómo puedo indicarlo en el atributo `pattern`? ¿O se debería comprobar con un script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hay 2 cosas que pueden importarte. Y dependiendo de eso será la solución.

- Si te importa que HTML valide tus campos antes de enviar un formulario

Con lo que todos te dijeron basta y sobra:

```
<input id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+">
```

- Si te importa que el usuario difícilmente pueda ver un caracter que no se permite en el campo

Entonces no te queda otra opción que utilizar un script.
Hay algunos más sencillos, pero el siguiente que pongo ya puede ser clasificado como rebuscado.

```js
class CampoNumerico {

  constructor(selector) {
    this.nodo = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.valor = '';
    
    this.empezarAEscucharEventos();
  }
  
  empezarAEscucharEventos() {
    this.nodo.addEventListener('keydown', function(evento) {
      const teclaPresionada = evento.key;
      const teclaPresionadaEsUnNumero =
        Number.isInteger(parseInt(teclaPresionada));

      const sePresionoUnaTeclaNoAdmitida = 
        teclaPresionada != 'ArrowDown' &&
        teclaPresionada != 'ArrowUp' &&
        teclaPresionada != 'ArrowLeft' &&
        teclaPresionada != 'ArrowRight' &&
        teclaPresionada != 'Backspace' &&
        teclaPresionada != 'Delete' &&
        teclaPresionada != 'Enter' &&
        !teclaPresionadaEsUnNumero;
      const comienzaPorCero = 
        this.nodo.value.length === 0 &&
        teclaPresionada == 0;

      if (sePresionoUnaTeclaNoAdmitida || comienzaPorCero) {
        evento.preventDefault(); 
      } else if (teclaPresionadaEsUnNumero) {
        this.valor += String(teclaPresionada);
      }

    }.bind(this));

    this.nodo.addEventListener('input', function(evento) {
      const cumpleFormatoEsperado = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+/).test(this.nodo.value);

      if (!cumpleFormatoEsperado) {
        this.nodo.value = this.valor;
      } else {
        this.valor = this.nodo.value;
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }

}

new CampoNumerico('#numero');
```

```html
<input id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+">
```

---

Para agregar otro campo, puedes instanciar otro objecto CampoNumerico pasándole algún selector válido.

```
new CampoNumerico('#otro-campo-a-validar');
```

***Nota***: Agregué una línea de código para que se pueda borrar con la tecla suprimir también.

---

De todas maneras, como dijo @Francisco Romero, las validaciones no deben quedar solo del lado del cliente. Son fáciles de saltar.
Para este caso, con solo prevenir la ejecución del script, e inspeccionar el campo para remover el pattern, el usuario ya podrá enviar lo que quiera al servidor.

---

Agrego una solución más sencilla, y más agradable para quienes usan javascript de manera clásica. 
Sin embargo, hay algunas diferencias con respecto a la solución anterior.

Diferencias con la anterior 
 - No permite pegar pegar valores aceptables en el campo. 
 - No permite arrastrar números válidos dentro de él. 
 - Acepta que el campo pueda borrarse completamente. (En ambas soluciones, este comportamiento se puede cambiar si se requiere).

```js
const campoNumerico = document.getElementById('campo-numerico');

campoNumerico.addEventListener('keydown', function(evento) {
  const teclaPresionada = evento.key;
  const teclaPresionadaEsUnNumero =
    Number.isInteger(parseInt(teclaPresionada));

  const sePresionoUnaTeclaNoAdmitida = 
    teclaPresionada != 'ArrowDown' &&
    teclaPresionada != 'ArrowUp' &&
    teclaPresionada != 'ArrowLeft' &&
    teclaPresionada != 'ArrowRight' &&
    teclaPresionada != 'Backspace' &&
    teclaPresionada != 'Delete' &&
    teclaPresionada != 'Enter' &&
    !teclaPresionadaEsUnNumero;
  const comienzaPorCero = 
    campoNumerico.value.length === 0 &&
    teclaPresionada == 0;

  if (sePresionoUnaTeclaNoAdmitida || comienzaPorCero) {
    evento.preventDefault(); 
  }

});
```

```html
<input id="campo-numerico" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" onpaste="return false;" onDrop="return false;" autocomplete=off>
```

Por último, si se quiere usar esta última solución para varios campos, recomendaría usarlo con delegación de eventos.

```js
const contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor-campos');

contenedor.addEventListener('keydown', function(evento) {
  const elemento = evento.target;
  if (elemento.className === 'campo-numerico') {
    const teclaPresionada = evento.key;
    const teclaPresionadaEsUnNumero =
      Number.isInteger(parseInt(teclaPresionada));

    const sePresionoUnaTeclaNoAdmitida = 
      teclaPresionada != 'ArrowDown' &&
      teclaPresionada != 'ArrowUp' &&
      teclaPresionada != 'ArrowLeft' &&
      teclaPresionada != 'ArrowRight' &&
      teclaPresionada != 'Backspace' &&
      teclaPresionada != 'Delete' &&
      teclaPresionada != 'Enter' &&
      !teclaPresionadaEsUnNumero;
    const comienzaPorCero = 
      elemento.value.length === 0 &&
      teclaPresionada == 0;

    if (sePresionoUnaTeclaNoAdmitida || comienzaPorCero) {
      evento.preventDefault(); 
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id = "contenedor-campos">
  <input class="campo-numerico" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" onpaste="return false;" onDrop="return false;" autocomplete=off>
  <input class="campo-numerico" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" onpaste="return false;" onDrop="return false;" autocomplete=off>
  <input class="campo-numerico" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" onpaste="return false;" onDrop="return false;" autocomplete=off>
</div>
```

Comment: Sinceramente pero desde mi punto de vista el Script que ha propuesto se puede simplificar muchísimo más y es completamente innecesario hacerlo así de largo.

Comment: Ahí agregué una solución simplificada y reducida. Sin embargo, el largo de las variables lo mantuve para que se entienda un poco más rápido qué es lo que hace el código en caso de querer cambiar algo. Además, que antes de enviar código javascript al cliente, todo esto normalmente se minificaría.

Comment: no me refería al largo del nombre de las variables eso es lo de menos, yo hablo de que a pesar de eso sobra y mucho.

Comment: Bueno, en la simplificación, son solo variables y *básicamente* un único *if*.

Answer (score 9):

Para usar el atributo  *pattern*, seria 
`pattern="[0-9]+"`

Answer (score 9):

EL patrón lo puedes asignar directamente en el HTML, el cual solo escribirá números.

Tambien está el input numérico que solo acepta números.

Y siendo números le puedes asignar un valor mínimo al estos inputs.

```html
    <input type="number" pattern="^[0-9]" title='Only Number' min="1" step="1">
    
    <input type="number" min="0">
```

Comment: Si por ejemplo introduzco -15 desde el teclado puedo introducirlo.

Comment: Para tomarlo en tiempo real sí va ser necesario usar script.

Answer (score 8):

En caso de que quisieras usar un `pattern` podrías utilizar `pattern="^[0-9]+"` para que al enviar el formulario te aparezca un error como que estás introduciendo un valor erróneo en el caso de que introduzcan un número negativo.

Además, si quieres prevenir que el usuario pueda introducir valores negativos de cualquier forma podrías usar `min="1"` para que desde el propio `input` solo pueda seleccionar valores mayores que uno.

Sin embargo, el paso anterior no impedirá que un usuario desde el teclado pueda introducir -15 por ejemplo, por lo que necesitarás de un script para controlar que nadie pueda introducir números negativos en tu `input`. Para ello he usado la función `onkeypress` y he indicado que si introducen un número negativo el número que se introduzca en el `input` sea 1.

**IMPORTANTE:** El hacer una validación en el lado del cliente mediante `Javascript` no es suficiente ya que este tipo de validaciones se pueden manipular. Deberías controlarlo también desde el lado del servidor para mayor seguridad en tu plataforma.

Ejemplo:

```js
var numero = document.getElementById('numero');

function comprueba(valor){
  if(valor.value < 0){
    valor.value = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="numero" type="number" onkeypress="comprueba(this)" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+">
```

Answer (score 7):

Con html5 puedes marcarlo directamente en el input.

Ejemplo: números enteros del 0 al 1000, escala de una en una unidad:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="1" name="num">
```

Más información [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp).

Answer (score 4):

Lo puedes hacer con `^[1-9]\d*$`.

Te obliga a introducir solamente números positivos mayores que cero. La validación se hace sin necesidad de scripts.

**Ejemplo:**

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="^[1-9]\d*$"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías usar dos formas distintas:

- [Input Type Number](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)
   `<input type="number" name="points" min="1" max="9" step="1">`
  **Atributo** `min`: Especifica el valor mínimo de un campo de entrada
  **Atributo** `max`: Especifica el valor máximo de un campo de entrada
  **Atributo** `step`: especifica los intervalos de número legales para un campo de entrada.
- [El atributo pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)
  `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{1}" title="Formato: 1 digito" />`
  `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="Formato: 3 dígitos" />`, es decir, `001`, etc.

**Ejemplo Input Type `Number`:**

```html
<form>
  <input type="number" name="points" min="1" max="9" step="1" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Ejemplo atributo `pattern`:**

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{1}" title="Formato: 1 digito" />
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{3}" title="Formato: 3 dígitos" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yo le agregue un min de "0" y cree una funcion en Js para validar:

```
<input type="number" min="0" onkeyup="validarNumero(this)" />
```

Y esta es mi función:

```
function validarNumero(value) {
   var valor = $(value).val();
    if (!isNaN(valor) && valor >= 0){
      $(value).val(valor);
    }else{
      $(value).val(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta respuesta me funciono solo cambie a if (!isNaN(valor) && valor >= 1) y la otra else a $(value).val(""); para que solo acepte número de +1 en adelante y si no, deje el campo vacío

Answer (score 1):

Otra forma más simplificada de hacerlo es recibir el evento del campo y verificar si la tecla que hemos presionado es `-`. Si esto cumple, evitamos el evento por defecto con `preventDefault()`:

```js
function evitarNegativo(e) {
  if (e.key === "-")
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeydown="evitarNegativo(event)" onpaste="return false;" onDrop="return false;" autocomplete="off">
```