# ¿Cómo validar input tipo number para aceptar sólo números positivos con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un input tipo number, y cuando tecleo éste me permite números negativos, lo cual no es correcto; lo estoy usando para elegir la cantidad de artículos, y obviamente no se pueden elegir productos negativos.
Lo quiero hacer con javascript, ya que si lo coloco de esta manera:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity[]"/>
```

Dentro de input no puede ponerse un min="0" por que en estos casos puede haber un usuario avanzado y modificar manualmente ese dato, y es por eso que necesito hacerlo con javascript. ¿Alguien puede orientarme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar un `input` `type=text` y con una expresión regular eliminar los caracteres no deseados, en tu caso solo quieres números positivos, por lo tanto la expresión regular sería: `/\D|\-/g`

```js
function el(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

el('cantidad').addEventListener('input',function() {
  var val = this.value;
  this.value = val.replace(/\D|\-/,'');
});
```

```html
<input id="cantidad" type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

En algún momento tuve este problema, pero me dejaba además de los negativos poner puntos y comas, por lo cual puede cancelar desde el teclado, le dejo un ejemplo:

```
jQuery('#idInput').on('keypress', function (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (e.keyCode == 101 || e.keyCode == 45 || e.keyCode == 46 || e.keyCode == 43 || e.keyCode == 44 || e.keyCode == 47) {
        return false;
    }
    soloNumeros(e.keyCode);
});

function soloNumeros(e) {
    var key = window.Event ? e.which : e.keyCode
        return (key >= 48 && key <= 57)
}
```

Comment: Estoy verificando su respuesta

Comment: @ArmandoBolaños hay varias respuestas a tu pregunta aquí: [¿Cómo permitir únicamente valores positivos en un <input>?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93416/cómo-permitir-únicamente-valores-positivos-en-un-input)

Comment: Ya revisé esa pregunta pero no es la respuesta que busco

Comment: @cristian tangarife, no logro implementar tu código, soy nuevo en la programacion de javascript

Comment: Utilice jQuery, facilita mucho el trabajo